# Cocos2d: Replaced scene is still active

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

i am trying to handle cocos2d, and got problem. I will try to be clear and short, i have a scene with files Level1.h and Level1.m 
http://pastebin.com/BdZqpXBb
and my next scene: http://pastebin.com/1YPy0E9f
when i switch from Level1.m to next scene, or main menu, seems like everything changes and i can't see anything from Level1.m, but sprites still are active, and play sounds when i touch them. why it's so ? how can i kill them and remove ? It's a problem with my Layers and Scenes logic or with memory management ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a memory management issue. Your scene has leaked, it has not been deallocated. Perhaps you're keeping a strong reference to it somewhere?

All those variables, they go in the @interface section within the curly brackets, not below @implementation. Because the way they are now makes them global variables, not per-instance variables. Since they're global, the references these variables hold on to will not be released when you change scenes.

Comment: nothing helps, i made new project, small one (easier to read it), two scenes, one sprite, and it's the same problem, here is my code:
HelloWorldLayer: 
http://pastebin.com/L7hZ7kvh
And other scene:
http://pastebin.com/y3XTNEhn

Comment: I added on my onExit method this line:
[[CCEventDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeMouseDelegate:self];
and seems like it works

Comment: if i write this line on my onExit method:
[[CCEventDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeMouseDelegate:self];
everything works fine in next scene, but i can't press on any menu items, they doesn't work, but sprites works. I insert also this line in my init method:
    [[CCEventDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addMouseDelegate:self priority:[self mouseDelegatePriority]];
Any ideas ?